# populate listview from json in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to populate a **list view** with the **json parsed** data .tell me the way to do it plz?

Comment: Which javascript frame work are you using (Sencha ,jQuery or anything else)?

Comment: The problem with your question is that there just isn't enough information to actually help you. I could make a bunch of assumptions and post some code but that wouldn't be very helpful. Perhaps you could add some information to your question? What do you mean by a list view? Are you using a JavaScript framework? etc...

Comment: i am new to phonegap application.pls tell me how to parse the json object?

Comment: Assuming all you want is how to parse the JSON string into an object, see the answer below.

Comment: pls tell how to hit an url in phonegap ?

Answer (score 0):

A JSON string can be parsed into a JavaScript object in PhoneGap using:

```
var myNewObject = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
```